# Laravel 5.8 + Apache — Subdomain configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost, laravel-5.8, debian-jessie, php-7.3

So basically my issue is about the routing of a subdomain (or multiple ones) to a single Laravel app.
To go more in details I have multiple **Route::group** and I want to have them "connect" to a specific subdomain.
For example:

- **account**.domain.co → `Route::domain('account.domain.co')→group(...`
- **visual**.domain.co → `Route::domain('visual.domain.co')→group(...`

---

I have configured my Virtual Hosts like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    [...]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName account.domain.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    [...]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName visual.domain.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, all the `DocumentRoot` are the same.
In theory with the Laravel configuration explained earlier it should work, but in reality **account.domain.co**, **visual.domain.co** and **domain.co** redirect all to the same application instead of their specific **Route::group**.

---

Here is the `web.php` of my app

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')→name('index');
[...]

Route::group([ 'domain' => 'account.domain.com', ],function() {
  Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index')→name('account.index');
  [...]
});

Route::group([ 'domain' => 'visual.domain.com', ],function() {
  Route::get('/', 'VisualController@index')→name('visual.index');
  [...]
});
```

My configuration is: `PHP 7.3`, `Debian 8 (jessie)`, `Apache 2.4.10` and `Laravel 5.8`.

Comment: Could you include your complete(obfuscated) Routes and Group definitions.  It is impossible to diagnose an ellipsis.

Comment: Sure @Strom , just edited the original post to include the web.php example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `Route::group`s without calling them.
For this example you probably don't need the groups at all; the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) is unclear as to that point. I have included them since it will not hurt anything.

The first two are for the default domain access methods (replaces the first route get('/') which was the only one taken in your code).

```
Route::domain('www.domain.com')->group(function() {
get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
})};

Route::domain('domain.com')->group(function() {
get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
})};

Route::domain('account.domain.com')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index')->name('account.index');
})};

Route::domain('visual.domain.com')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/', 'VisualController@index')->name('visual.index');
})};
//...
```

Comment: Oh ok so from what I understand I should group everysingle route even and set a « domain » to them, right ?

Comment: Just tested it, and I have to say that you saved me from another headache. Thank you very much for your precious help!